# Variables aren't passing from one function to another why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm a Python beginner and trying to build upon my code below. I have the base working and want to collect the data from the calculator and store it in a dictionary. I created the last function to do this, but I can't pass the variables from bmi_metrics(). Why?

```
#Intro to BMI Calculator
print("Welcome to my BMI calculator!")
print("Give me your height and weight, I'll calculate your Body Mass Index")

# Gather BMI metrics from user and create two loops that only accept number inputs for height/weight
def bmi_metrics(): 
    get_name = (input("\nWhat's your name?  "))

    while True:
        try:
            get_height = float(input(f"\nHi {get_name.title()}, please enter your height in inches: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Oops, that doesn't look like a number, try again.")
    while True:
        try:
            get_weight = float(input("Please enter your weight in pounds: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Oops, that doesn't look like a number, try again.")

   #Calculate BMI from height and weight input
    BMI = (get_weight  * 703) / (get_height ** 2)        

    #Display user BMI and weight category back to them
    print(f"{get_name.title()}, your BMI is {BMI:.2f}")
    if BMI <= 18.5:
        print(f"A person with a BMI of {BMI:.2f} is underwieght ")
    elif BMI <= 24.9:
        print(f"A person with a BMI of {BMI:.2f} is normal weight ")
    elif BMI <= 29.9:
        print(f"A person with a BMI of {BMI:.2f} is overweight ")
    else:
        print(f"A person with a BMI of {BMI:.2f} is obese")

    return get_name, get_height, get_weight, BMI
    
#Prompt user to run calculator again       
def prompt_again(): 
    while True:
        run_again = input("\nWould you like to do another calculation (y/n)? ")
        if run_again == 'y':
            bmi_metrics()
        elif run_again == 'Y':
            bmi_metrics()
        elif run_again == 'N':
            break
        elif run_again == 'n':
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter 'y' or 'n' ")
    print("Thanks for playing!")

#Collect Name/BMI data and place it in an empty dictionary
def calc_data():
    calc_results = {"Name": " ", "BMI": " "}
    get_name = name

    
bmi_metrics()
prompt_again()
```

Comment: "I can't pass the variables from bmi_metrics()"—What do you mean? Please describe the problem you are having

Comment: When you call `bmi_metrics()` you need to do something with the return value or it just gets dropped on the floor.  Do `name, height, weight, bmi = bmi_metrics()`, and then put those values into your dictionary.

Comment: Or `current_bmi=bmi_metrics()` if you want to leave the values in a tuple to unpack later

Comment: I think the issue is that you believe that variables defined inside a function are by default global variables. This is not the case. Additionally when you call bmi_metrics() the values it returns likely want to be used to assign new variables.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I now realize the mistake after reading the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello :) You are missing the storage of the returned values from the call at the end of the script:

```
get_name, get_height, get_weight, BMI = bmi_metrics()
```

Otherwise, the result is not stored. You have to keep in mind that all variables in python defined inside a method are local to the method unless you store them in an object, return them as result of the method or define them as global variables. If you want to use the resulting values in another function you need to pass them as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This makes more sense to me now.